# Playing videos on VirtualBox Mac OS X guest on Ubuntu 13.04 as host

Tags: macos, video, virtualbox

I managed to install Mac OS X Moutain Lion as a VirtualBox guest OS on Ubuntu 13.04 as host.

I need to test a web app which plays HTML5 videos on Safari 6. Unfortunately, I can’t play any video on Moutain Lion (neither HTML5 one nor a .mp4 with Quicktime).

I guess it’s a codec or video card driver problem but I can't find a clue on how to fix this. Can anyone suggest an idea?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Installing Apple operating systems on non-Apple hardware violates the license agreement for the OS, and is therefore [off topic for this site](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Let's chat on [meta] or [chat] - virtualized OS isn't something we explicitly have discouraged - just hackintosh where you run the OS on hardware directly. This still might end up being better asked on Super User or a ubuntu / linux side of stack exchange, but I don't see it as needing to be closed here.

Answer (score 2):

OS X uses [QE/CI (Quartz Extreme/Core Image)](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/278159-what-are-quartz-extreme-and-core-image-qeci/) for graphics acceleration. Unless you're using an actual Mac or are running a modified version of OS X directly on PC hardware, you won't get full acceleration. Furthermore, VirtualBox support for OS X is experimental and doesn't include Guest Additions.

Looking around a bit, it seems some have had success with [modified SVGA drivers](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/188962-vmware-svga-ii-display-driver-for-os-x-v125/) in VMWare. It may get you better performance overall, but it still won't enable QE/CI (and thus no video playback), and doesn't work with VirtualBox anyway.